# Citrix users cannot add locations to favorites in Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, citrix, roaming-profile

Citrix users (Windows Server 2008R2/XenDesktop 7 Published Desktops) are unable to drag locations to "Favorites" in Explorer. Icon changes to a red "no" symbol. Users have roaming profiles.

Comment: To be specific , this isn't favorites in IE, this is the Favorites in the left pane of explorer, typically stored in %userdir%\links